# How to remove stop words from list of lists in python

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have a set of tweets that is formatted as a list of lists. The code I used works to remove the stop words, but it doesn't return a list of lists, but rather one big list. I need it to stay as a list of lists to do naive bayes later, so how can I change it?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

OAGTokensWOStop = []
for i in range(2708):
    for tweet in OAG_Tokenized[i]:
        if tweet not in stop_words:
            OAGTokensWOStop.append(tweet)
```

I received on big list with all the words sans stop words, but I need the output to remain as a list of lists.

Comment: What are the sublists in your list of lists?

Comment: maybe you should create new list inside `for` loop, add words inside this loop and finally add list to main-list at the end.

Comment: So the list of lists is in the format [['well', 'said','] , ['loot', 'of', 'people'], ...]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating yourself a single list.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

OAGTokensWOStop = []
for item in OAG_Tokenized:
    temp = []
    for tweet in item:
        if tweet not in stop_words:
            temp.append(tweet)
    OAGTokensWOStop.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

`append(tweet)` is appending the content of the tweet to the list that is `OAGTokensWOStop`.

You want it to append the tweet as a list, hence you should do this instead:

```
import numpy as np
OAGTokensWOStop = []
for i in range(2708):
    for tweet in OAG_Tokenized[i]:
        if tweet not in stop_words:
            OAGTokensWOStop.append(np.array(tweet))
```

Here you are appending the tweet as a numpy array to the list. Hence creating a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess.

You have to create empty list inside `for` loop, add words to this list and finally add list to `OAGTokensWOStop` at the end of loop.

```
OAGTokensWOStop = []
for i in range(2708):

    row = []
    for tweet in OAG_Tokenized[i]:
        if tweet not in stop_words:
            row.append(tweet)

    OAGTokensWOStop.append(row)
```